# ¿Cómo hacer dos semáforos opuestos?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

Tengo un pequeño problema: Debo realizar dos semáforos, uno para la *Calle 1* y otro para la *Calle 2*. Teniendo en cuenta que mientras esté verde en la *Calle 1* en la *Calle 2* debe estar rojo y viceversa.

Tengo un problema con los intervalos de tiempo, puesto que inician bien pero luego se van como acelerando y casi se juntan, hasta que se pierde la sincronización.

Les dejaré el código con *HTML* y *JavaScript*:

```js
function start() {
  cambios(1);
  cambios(2);
}
function cambios(id) {

  var cont = 1;
  var bomb1;
  bomb1 = document.getElementById("bombillo"+id);

  function colorRojo() {
    if (cont == 1) {

      bomb1.style.background = "red";
      cont += 2;
    }
  }

  window.setInterval(colorRojo, 5000);
  window.clearInterval(colorRojo);

  function colorAmarillo() {

    if (cont == 2) {
      bomb1.style.background = "yellow";
      cont -= 1;
    }
  }
  window.setInterval(colorAmarillo, 5000);
  window.clearInterval(colorAmarillo);

  function colorVerde() {

    if (cont == 3) {

      bomb1.style.background = "green";
      cont -= 1;
    }
  }

  window.setInterval(colorVerde, 7000);
  window.clearInterval(colorVerde);
}
start()
```

```css
#bombillo1 {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background-color: green;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 25px auto;
 transition: background 300ms;
}
#bombillo2 {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 25px auto;
 transition: background 300ms;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery usado como dependencia de Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<div class="bombillo" id="bombillo1"></div>
<div class="bombillo" id="bombillo2"></div>

<div class="btn-group"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Porqué dos hilos de ejecución por separado? Tienes 4 estados (verde1, amarillo1, verde2, amarillo2) que se suceden cíclicamente, basta con ir llamando sucesivamente al mismo método para calcular el siguiente estado y cambiar los colores de todos los semáforos simultáneamente. Lo que tu quieres hacer (dos "procesos" por separado que se ejecuten de forma coordinada sin coordinación entre ambos requieren de un sistema de tiempo real, y eso implica un HW y un SO específicos para sistemas de tiempo real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te paso el script en JQuery:

```
var estado = 'verde';
var animation;
function fnSemaforo(){
    clearInterval(animation);
  var bombilla = $(".bombillo");
  var inAction = 0;
    if(estado === 'verde' && inAction===0){
      bombilla.css("background-color","yellow");
      estado = 'amarillo';
      inAction=1;
    }
    if(estado === 'amarillo' && inAction===0){
      bombilla.css("background-color","red");
      estado = 'rojo';
      inAction=1;
    }
    if(estado === 'rojo' && inAction===0){
      bombilla.css("background-color","green");
      estado = 'verde';
      inAction=1;
    }

    animation = window.setInterval("fnSemaforo()",500);
}
```

Sólo tienes que agregar la funcion **fnSemaforo** en el bloque *ready*, de la siguiente manera:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    fnSemaforo();
})
```

Espero te sea de utilidad!
Exitos!

**edit:** Agrego el codigo en JS puro, por si te hace falta:

```
var estado = 'verde';
var animation;
function test(){
    clearInterval(animation);
  var bombilla = document.getElementById("bombillo1");
  var inAction = 0;
    if(estado === 'verde' && inAction===0){
      bombilla.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      estado = 'amarillo';
      inAction=1;
    }
    if(estado === 'amarillo' && inAction===0){
      bombilla.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      estado = 'rojo';
      inAction=1;
    }
    if(estado === 'rojo' && inAction===0){
      bombilla.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      estado = 'verde';
      inAction=1;
    }

    animation = window.setInterval("test()",500);
}
```

Comment: No veo la etiqueta **jQuery** en su pregunta. Quizás el esté aprendiendo JavaScript y no necesita de librerías aún. Sería mejor proporcionar una respuesta en base a las preferencias del usuario.

Comment: @Guz Si te fijás en el HTML, está incluyendo JQuery 3.3.1 min. Por eso mi respuesta en JQuery. Podes agregarle la etiqueta JQuery a la pregunta ;)

Comment: Lo está agregando como dependencia de Bootstrap, pero en su código no lo usa. Dejémoslo así ;)

Comment: @Guz agregué la alternativa en JS vainilla por las dudas! De paso, podrías ponerle un voto a mi respuesta :)

Comment: Genial, mejor así ;)

Comment: @Guz no te olvide de votar :)

Comment: Excelente bro, Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 7):

Yo te recomiendo hacer esto vía [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) ya que tiene muchas ventajas sobre `setInterval/setTimeout`. Algunas ventajas son un mejor FPS, gasta menos CPU y batería, entre otras. Además, si quieres **sincronización** entre ambos semáforos debes implementar el [patrón Observador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) (también llamado pub/sub).

**Ejemplo**

```js
class Observer {

  constructor() {
    this.observers = [];
  }

  subscribe(semaphore) {
    semaphore.observers.push(this);
  }

  publish() {
    this.observers.forEach(ob => ob.semaphoreChange(this.currentLight));
  }
}

class Semaphore extends Observer {

  constructor(id) {
    super();
    this.$el = document.querySelector(id);
    this.count = 0;
    this.rafid = 0;
    this.currentLight = '';
    this.breakpoints = {
      green: 5,
      red: 8,
      ambar: 10
    };
  }

  start() {
    this.rafid = requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
  }

  stop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.rafid);
  }

  loop(currTime) {
    let time = Math.round(currTime / 1000) - this.count;

    if (time < this.breakpoints.green &&
      this.currentLight !== 'green') {
      this.currentLight = 'green';
      this.updateColor();
      this.publish();
    }

    if (time >= this.breakpoints.green &&
      time < this.breakpoints.red &&
      this.currentLight !== 'red') {
      this.currentLight = 'red';
      this.updateColor();
      this.publish();
    }

    if (time >= this.breakpoints.red &&
      time < this.breakpoints.ambar &&
      this.currentLight !== 'ambar') {
      this.currentLight = 'ambar';
      this.updateColor();
      this.publish();
    }

    if (time >= this.breakpoints.ambar) {
      this.count += time;
    }

    this.rafid = requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
  }

  updateColor() {
    this.$el.className = `semaphore ${this.currentLight}`;
  }

  semaphoreChange(color) {
    if (color === 'green') {
      this.$el.className = 'semaphore red';
    } else if (color === 'red') {
      this.$el.className = 'semaphore green';
    } else {
      this.$el.className = `semaphore ${color}`;
    }
  }
}

let semaphore1 = new Semaphore('#s1');
let semaphore2 = new Semaphore('#s2');

semaphore2.subscribe(semaphore1);
semaphore1.start();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');


.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.street {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: -4px;
  width: 50%;
}

h1 {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.semaphore {
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
  height: 150px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 150px;
}

.semaphore.green {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.semaphore.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.semaphore.ambar {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="street street-1">
    <h1>Street 1</h1>
    <div id="s1" class="semaphore"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="street street-2">
    <h1>Street 2</h1>
    <div id="s2" class="semaphore"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

La clase `Observer` solo implementa de manera básica el patrón Observador, definiendo los métodos `subscribe` para subscribirse a otro semáforo y el método `publish` para notificar a los semáforos "observadores" cuando se ha producido un cambio de luz.

La clase `Semaphore` como puedes observar no tiene nada fuera de lo común. La propiedad `breakpoints` son los "puntos de quiebre" en el que el semáforo debe cambiar. En este ejemplo, el verde durará 5, el rojo 3 y el ámbar 2.

Comment: Hola @Guz la clase observer la haces con javascript?

Comment: Claro, todo el código está en JavaScript ES6 (versión del 2015). Si quieres darle soporte a navegadores menos modernos solo copia el código y traspílalo con Babel para que te genere código JavaScript viejo.

Comment: Excelente amigo mio, Esto me funciono de maravilla. muchas gracias ahora ya tengo dos metodos funcionales de como reslver eso y pues la logica para otro proyecto que lo requiera.